# Default value of Django's model doesn't appear in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I created following test model. The model contains various fields which have ***default*** value.

```python
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
    z = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

After that, I run migration command, and Django exported following migration code. As you can see, default values are filled using ***default*** parameters.

```python
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TestModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=32)),
                ('x', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('y', models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)),
                ('z', models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

And finally, I got following MySQL code using Django's migration command.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `base_testmodel` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    `x` integer NOT NULL, 
    `y` integer NULL, 
    `z` integer NULL
    );
COMMIT;
```

**Question**: Although, I set default values as 1 and 0, It doesn't appear in SQL code. Is this a feature of Django? - or - What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you set a default for a model field in Django, it isn't included in the SQL schema generated by Django.

As long as you create your model instances using the ORM, then this doesn't matter, as Django will set the default value. However, if you create model instances using raw SQL, then you do need to make sure you use the default value for the field if required.

There is a [ticket 470](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470) for adding default values to the SQL schema, but it has been closed as won't fix. Remember than `default` can be a callable as well as a constant. It wouldn't be possible to add these callables as defaults to the SQL schema.

If you really require the default to be added to the SQL schema, you could run the alter table statement manually, or add it to a migration.

Comment: Update:  The linked ticket was changed about 5 months ago to "Accepted"/"New Feature", so this may be coming at some point eventually.

Comment: @Izkata it's 2021 and that feature is still coming but at least it has a patch now:)

Comment: It still matters even if you only use Django. When you add a new not-null field, and first run migrations, then redeploy the backend (all this without any downtime), you get IntegrityErrors in the meanwhile. Database defaults would solve this. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470#comment:30

Comment: @LaszloTreszkai you can avoid those integrity errors by creating the field with `null=True`, deploying the backend, setting all bill values, then finally adding the not null constraint.

Comment: After 18 years this was finally added :) https://github.com/django/django/pull/16092