# Django model choice field default value not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a basic Django site.

I have added a Model field named 'status' in the models.py file as shown below:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    USED_STATUS = (
        ('Y', 'Used'),
        ('N', 'Not used'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USED_STATUS, default=USED_STATUS[1][0])
```

But when I phpmyadmin into the database, the Default Value of 'status' model field is **None** which should have been **'N'**.
Also when I try to *INSERT* a record using Python SQL script into the same Database table, it throws an error: "**Warning: (1364, "Field 'status' doesn't have a default value")**". I have search the whole forum but can't find any similar problem, Please help.

Comment: Did you apply the migration?

Comment: Yes I have applied the migration multiple times. Even I have tried deleting the status field, apply migration, then recreate the status model field then again apply migration.

Comment: The default is only used by Django, [it is not set in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280343/default-value-of-djangos-model-doesnt-appear-in-sql). If you use phpmyadmin or a Python script which does not use the ORM, then the default will not be used.

Comment: Ok thanks this explains this behavior. Is there any way I can insert the value using other script and not interfere with Django's default option? Can I insert value 'N' using the script?

Comment: It's probably more reliable to use the django ORM for most data insertions. You can end up with an inconsistent schema if you manipulate the database directly.

Comment: Yes I don't wan't to mess the schema. Thanks.

Comment: You can still use the ORM to input the needed default data. Is the default value needed for some reason?

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to use ORM to input the default value. This status Model field is a part of table which contains other Models fields including 'Name', 'email' etc,. So I wanted to fill the values in the database providing values of all other fields but 'status' field which should have been default to 'N'.

Answer (score 1):

The default values added in models will not reflect in the SQL DDL statements generated. It's this way most likely since nothing is stopping people from using callables as defaults which run complex code to figure out defaults. The callables obviously cannot be substituted into the DB.

You are better off using the ORM directly. In case you wish to communicate with you DB using the Django ORM from an independent python script, you could initialize the script and call `import django; django.setup()` which will pretty much ensure you can import your models and run queries via the ORM.

**Note**: You may have to export the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable in order for this to work.

Comment: This seems to be the best alternative solution. Thanks I will try and update status here.